# use of an elif statement in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Hi guys I am using python 3, and I am having trouble doing this code. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

I have this docstring that I have to do for practice but I am getting failures from the automarker. this is the docstring

```
'''(number) -> str

Return the size of a drink given the amount of volume of a beverage (in mL)
served. If a volume does not correspond to a drink size, return "invalid".

A kid-sized drink is any beverage of at least 100 mL but smaller
    than a large drink that isn't another drink size.
A small drink contains 200 mL of beverage.
A medium drink contains 300 mL of beverage.
A large drink contains 400 mL of beverage.
A jumbo drink contains 600 mL of beverage.
A promotional-sized drink is any beverage larger than a large drink that
    isn't another drink size.

>>> drink_size(-20)
'invalid'
>>> drink_size(200)
'small'
>>> drink_size(120)
'kid-sized'
'''
```

and this is what my code looks like

```
def drink_size(volume):
    if 100 <= volume < 400 and volume != 200 and volume != 300:
        return ('kid-sized')
    elif volume == 200:
        return ('small drink')
    elif volume == 300:
        return ('medium drink')
    elif volume == 400:
        return ('large drink')
    elif volume == 600:
        return ('jumbo drink')
    elif volume > 400 and volume != 600:
        return ('promotionl-sized')
    else:
        return ('invalid')
```

please help out i do not know why its not working

Comment: Try `if (100 <= volume < 400) and volume != 200 and volume != 300`

Comment: What's the error message?  How did you produce it?

Comment: If you already have `elif volume == 600`, by the way, you don’t have to check `volume != 600` in the next one.

Comment: The criterion for a kid-sized drink isn't clear. Is it a drink that's between 100 and 200? Is it any drink that isn't an exact size and smaller than 400?

Comment: Assuming that this "automarker" is an automated grading program through which you submit your assignment, and that the problems only occur with this "automarker" and not before, the problem is most likely that you're returning `'small drink'` instead of `'small'` as in the docstring, and likewise for the other drinks (and also "promotional" is misspelled).

Comment: this is the only error im having now. Test description:
Check to make sure no restricted keywords and basic check for adherence to style guidelines. Checks for inefficient use of if-statements. Only one 'and' is permitted.

Message:
RestrictedError
Your answer is too complicated: too many uses of comparisons.

Comment: Those complaints are just about your style, they're not actual errors.

Comment: so how do i fix that one ??

Comment: Check for specific sizes first, then the ranges.  You won't need `and`.  Also, parentheses aren't needed in `return` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be simplified, by checking exact values first, then ranges values and finally reject if the value doesn't respect any condition (`< 100` there):

```
def drink_size(volume):
    # specific size check
    if volume == 200:
        return 'small'
    elif volume == 300:
        return 'medium'
    elif volume == 400:
        return 'large'
    elif volume == 600:
        return 'jumbo'

    # Range check
    elif 100 <= volume < 400:
        return 'kid-sized'
    elif volume > 400:
        return 'promotional-sized'
    else:
        return 'invalid'
```

You could even refactor to avoid this long suite of `if` and make your code more readable:

```
# Create a dictionary of volume to verbose size
sizes = {200: 'small', 300: 'medium', 400: 'large', 600: 'jumbo'}

def drink_size(volume):
    # specific size check
    if volume in sizes:
        return sizes[volume]

    # Range check
    elif 100 <= volume < 400:
        return 'kid-sized'
    elif volume > 400:
        return 'promotional-sized'
    else:
        return 'invalid'
```